# SQL Server: rearrange and flatten out table of values?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on a Stored Procedure that retrieves certain values from my database.

I am able to get the values I need, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to order them they way I need.

Below is what I'm trying to achieve. I already have table properties (left), and need to create table newProperties by running a SELECT on properties.

Please note:

- the field **valueTypeID** will ALWAYS be either 68 or 80.
- the field **value** will never be the same. Each value will be a long string of chars that changes for each value (I have simplified for my question)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be the starting point of your SELECT statement:

```
select
  p.genericID,
  p68.Value as ValueTypeId68,
  p80.Value as ValueTypeId80
from partials p
join partialsProps p68
  on p.genericId = p68.genericId
  and p68.valueTypeID = 68
join partialsProps p80
  on p.genericId = p80.genericId
  and p80.valueTypeID = 80
```

You can add the `@cycle` and `@clientAccountID` conditions on top of it.

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/472de/1

Answer (score 0):

Are 68 and 80 the only possible values for the column valueTypeID? if it's so then the answer provided by w0lf should work for you though I won't say it is the only solution.

However, if there can be multiple values for valueTypeID apart from 60 and 80 then I would like to propose a solution here.

I am assuming that you have numeric and non-numeric values in the column value but the problem  you are having is that the numeric and non numeric values come together in a single column hence you want to separate them out. This is the scenario I imagine.

**NOTE:** If this does not provide you satisfactory solution, please provide the scenario in detail.

[GO to SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74795/2)

```
-- Create table as you have provided in the question

CREATE TABLE #partials
([genericID] int);

INSERT INTO #partials ([genericID])
VALUES (11),(12),(13),(14);



CREATE TABLE #partialsProps
([genericID] int, [valueTypeID] int, [Value] varchar(1));

-- Insert values similar 

INSERT INTO #partialsProps
([genericID], [valueTypeID], [Value])
VALUES
(11, 68, 'A'),
(11, 80, '1'),
(12, 68, 'Z'),
(12, 80, '2'),
(13, 68, 'B'),
(13, 80, '3'),
(14, 68, 'Y'),
(14, 80, '4')
```

;

```
select r1.value as Val1,r2.Value as Val2 from 
(select pp.genericID,value, valueTypeID from #partialsProps pp join #partials p on    
       p.genericID = pp.genericID
   where ISNUMERIC(Value) = 0 group by valueTypeID, value ,pp.genericID) r1
join
(select pp.genericID,value, valueTypeID from #partialsProps pp join #partials p on 
        p.genericID = pp.genericID
   where ISNUMERIC(Value) = 1 group by valueTypeID, value ,pp.genericID) r2
   on r1.genericID = r2.genericID ;

 drop table #partials;
 drop table #partialsProps;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've realized my question is not so clear. I have too much stuff going on. I will clear it up right now so its easier to understand, thanks for your help.

Comment: Please take a second look, I have simplified for your better understanding.

Comment: Why isn't the solution given by @w0lf working for you?